# How can I display a list of all buffers when clicking on the buffer name?

Tags: buffers

[image: Buffer name]

Is there a way to do this? Currently, the click events are bound to previous/next buffer, but I would rather like to see a list of all buffers when I click the buffer name. Perhaps, it could make use of a simple OS native context menu similar to the major and minor mode buttons:

[image: OS native context menu]

Comment: Not an answer, but what you ask for doesn't seem particularly useful to me (I typically have 300-600 buffers open). I mean, it's not a kind of info which is easily displayed using drop-down. What if clicking the buffer name instead opened the buffer with the list of all buffers?

Comment: Interesting, I never have more than ten buffers open at a time. What is the advantage of having that many buffers open vs., say, using `ag` to find a particular file?

Comment: Well, it's mostly because they pile up over time... but other than that, there are few operations I use very often from `Ibuffer` which work on multiple buffers. Plus I keep several shells open and lots of Dired buffers on several machines... but usually about 1/3 of all buffers aren't associated with files: all kinds of shells or buffers which collect process output (logs) etc. Also mail adds a lot of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(define-key mode-line-buffer-identification-keymap [mode-line mouse-3] 'list-buffers)
```

That does not show buffers whose names begin with a space.  If you really want to show *all* buffers, then try this instead:

```el
(define-key mode-line-buffer-identification-keymap
            [mode-line mouse-3]
            (lambda ()
              (interactive)
              (display-buffer (list-buffers-noselect nil (buffer-list)))))
```

(However, I agree with those who commented that this is a very useful thing to do.)